# make JScrollPane's appearance the same as MAC's scrollbar

Tags: java, jscrollpane

is it possible to get a scroll bar to look like this (the last one)?
[image: sa]
if so, how?
At the moment I am using WebL&F's scroll bar, but would want the last one shown.

Answer (score 0):

Try `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());`.

This will take the  look and feel of your system.

Comment: on windows, not MAC. Why'd I have a MAC?

Comment: Because you want the Mac L&F? And because you didn't write you were having Windows?

Comment: Alright, fair argument. Do you have any idea on how I could do this though?

Comment: You could override the `paint(Graphics)` method of the Scrollbar.